# python Schema in parquet file was different

Tags: python-3.x, parquet, dask

I converted a large csv file (~20GB) to parquet format via dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_csv('/storage/news_data/train_data.csv', dtype={'type': 'str'})
ddf.to_parquet('/storage/data/train/parquet')
```

and when I am trying to read it back in I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Schema in /storage/data/train/parquet/part.42.parquet was different. 
type: null
content: string
title: string

vs

type: string
content: string
title: string
```

I tried to `dropna()` but the file is too large to handle.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: We have a similar problem - with one of the partitions exported is empty